# Find INT to LONG conversions at compile time

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

Is there a way to detect int to long or long to int at compile time?
I have a large project that needs to change an ID from int to long.

I am worried that I missed something.

Need to detect things like
Long myid = ResultSet.getInt("ID");

ect...

Comment: ResultSet.getInt("ID"); returns an int. I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you have an OOP design then you should just see where the specific `myid` getter and setter are invoked. Else there is just brute force search, e.g. search for `"ID"` or `myid` etc.

Comment: Source code analysis? Bytecode analysis? Refactoring while coding? Its just unclear what you want to do.

Comment: You can assign ints to longs without a problem. If you try and assign a long to an int it won't compile. You don't have a problem unless you have untyped (e..g, Object) returns.

Comment: "Need to detect things like `Long myid = ResultSet.getInt("ID");`" The compiler would find things like that: `int`s don't get autoboxed to `Long`.